# EPPlus formula not working without calling Calculate

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I've tried to use two functions in excel [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-A5DCF0DD-996D-40A4-A822-B56B061328BD) and [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-E8DFFD45-C762-47D6-BF89-533F4A37673A) and according to [EPPlus codeplex, these should be supported](https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Supported%20functions&referringTitle=About%20Formula%20calculation). Everytime I open the file, there's a warning message saying that something is broken and asks if I want to repare the document, and when it opens, all formulas are gone. When repairing the document a dialog is shown saying that the formula has been removed from `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml-del`.

I can put the formulas manually into the spreedsheet and they work, but the only way to get any data to show in the generated xlsx file is to call `Calculate()` on the worksheet. This will output the data correctly, but what I need is to have the formulas inside the document.

Here's a small example of formulas I've tried

```
private byte[] TestingFormula()
{
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(_helper.GetTemplateStream("TEST.xlsx")))
    {
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

        ws.Cells["A4"].Formula = "INDEX($C$1:$D$24;4;2)";
        ws.Cells["A6"].Formula = "INDEX(C1:D24;6;2)";

        ws.Cells["B26"].Formula = "MATCH($B$12;$C$1:$D$1;0)";

        // sum works as expected
        //ws.Cells["D25"].Formula = "SUM(D2:D24)";

        //pck.Workbook.Calculate();
        //pck.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
        return pck.GetAsByteArray();
    }
}
```

> The TEST.xlsx is just a template that looks like this

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do your formulas use semi-colons instead of commas? I haven't tested, but I would think `"INDEX($C$1:$D$24,4,2)"` would work just fine.

Comment: Used existing formulas that I just copied. Using commas instead of semicolon actually solved the problem so I guess that epplus does not handle semicolons, just Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use commas instead of semicolons in your formulas:

```
ws.Cells["A4"].Formula = "INDEX($C$1:$D$24,4,2)";
ws.Cells["A6"].Formula = "INDEX(C1:D24,6,2)";

ws.Cells["B26"].Formula = "MATCH($B$12,$C$1:$D$1,0)";
```

I'm guessing when you enter semicolons directly in Excel, MS fixes the formula on the fly.  The actual XML probably requires commas, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer by reasra (I can't comment yet). This is documented under the "Some common mistakes" on this page:

https://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=About%20Formula%20calculation&referringTitle=Documentation

- Don't use localized function names. Only english names (such as SUM, IF, VLOOKUP, etc) are supported.
- Don't use semicolon as a separator between function arguments. Only comma is supported.
- Don't add the leading = sign in your formula. "=SUM(A1:A2)" is wrong, "SUM(A1:A2)" is correct